# Error "Symbol's value as variable is void: ftp_site_connect" on function running

Tags: emacs

I get the error "Symbol's value as variable is void: ftp_site_connect" on function running. I been checking the other questions with the similar error "Symbol's value as variable is void" on Stackoverflow but none of them seems to solve the problem.

```
(defun ftp_site_connect()
  (interactive)
  ( ange-ftp-set-passwd "ftp.site.com" "username" "password" )
  ( find-file "/username@ftp.site.com:/" )
  )

(eval 'ftp_site_connect)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I tested the same code without the function definition an it works. It seems to produce the error just when is inside a function definition.

Comment: `(eval 'ftp_site_connect)`: That's not the syntax for a function call, take a look at [An Introduction to Programming in Emacs Lisp: Run a Program](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/Run-a-Program.html)

Comment: @npostavs: Consider posting that as an answer. (And show the OP what s?he should have used instead, for example.)

Comment: @Drew: I was hoping the OP might read the link and then self-answer.

Comment: @npostavs: Good. Then please check back in a day or two. It's good to make clear that a question is answered - both to those who might have the same question and to those who might come here trying to help with an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well thanks to @npostavs it seems I found the problem.

After modifying the code as the info on the link @npostavs gave me ( the 'function in the code is wrong the 'format is for lists not for functions ) the following changed code seemed to work but it generated another error.

```
(defun ftp_site_connect()
  (interactive)
  ( ange-ftp-set-passwd "ftp.site.com" "username" "password" )
  ( find-file "/username@ftp.site.com:/" )
  )

(ftp_site_connect)
```

So, I found out that the function ange-ftp-set-passwd didn't exist on my server and that I had to setup the passwords through the .netrc file instead doing it inline. After changing again the code now seems to work perfectly.

```
;; Add first the user and password to the .netrc file like this:
;; machine HOST login NAME password PASSWD
;; and change the permissions on that file to chmod 600
;; -------------------------------------------------------------
(defun ftp_site_connect()
      (interactive)
      ( find-file "/username@ftp.site.com:/" )
      )

    (ftp_site_connect)
```

Thank you everyone for your help.

Comment: You might find evaluating `(require 'ange-ftp)` will define `ange-ftp-set-passwd`, but keeping passwords in .netrc is a better idea anyway, IMO.